# Why does += reset the value of the variable it's operating on to nil?

Tags: ruby

Taking this piece of code as an example:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :options, :list

  def initialize
    @list    = []
    @options = { published_at_end: 'NOW', published_at_start: 'NOW-2DAYS' }
  end

  def run
    # If you replace this comment with a debugger, the value of list is nil
    list += _some_method(options)
    return list
  end

  private

  def _some_method(options)
    [options[:published_at_start], 1, 2, 3, 4, options[:published_at_end]]
  end
end
```

If you copy/paste that into irb, then run:

- `t = Thing.new`
- `t.run`

It will output this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

If you remove the `+=` line (leaving just the `return` line), it returns `[]`... So from what I can tell, it's just the presence of `+=` that sets `list` to `nil`.
I also find it interesting that it's value is `nil` in the line *before* the `+=` call (see my comment in the code example).

Alternatively, if you use `<<` with `flatten` instead, you'll get the expected result:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :options, :list

  def initialize
    @list    = []
    @options = { published_at_end: 'NOW', published_at_start: 'NOW-2DAYS' }
  end

  def run
    list << _some_method(options)
    list.flatten
  end

  private

  def _some_method(options)
    [options[:published_at_start], 1, 2, 3, 4, options[:published_at_end]]
  end
end
```

If you copy/paste that into irb, then run:

- `t = Thing.new`
- `t.run`

It will output `['NOW-2DAYS', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'NOW']`.

---

Why does `+=` reset the value of `list` to `nil`?
Additionally, how does it set its value to `nil` prior to `+=` being called?

Semi-related / helpful side note - I'm going to use shovel (`<<`) with `flatten` because of [performance reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685182), but I'm still interested why the variable gets reset to `nil`.

Answer (score 7):

`list += [1, 2, 3]` is equivalent to:

```
list = list + [1, 2, 3]
```

Because this is an [assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html), Ruby creates a new *local variable* `list`, shadowing your `list` method. From the documentation:

> When using method assignment you must always have a receiver. If you do not have a receiver, Ruby assumes you are assigning to a local variable

More specifically, the local variable `list` is created when the parser encounters `list =`. Like uninitialized instance variables and global variables, it has a value of `nil`. Attempting to evaluate the assignment's right-hand side `list + [1, 2, 3]` therefore fails, because it is equivalent to:

```
nil + [1, 2, 3]
# NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

So to get the expected result, you have to provide an explicit receiver:

```
self.list += [1, 2, 3]
```

Or directly assign to the instance variable:

```
@list += [1, 2, 3]
```

Or use a method that modifies the receiver:

```
list.concat [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Ah, I see - so that "Ruby creates a new local variable `list`" part happens sometime prior to the line that contains `+=` ... That's why if I add `puts list` just prior to the `+=` line, it outputs `nil` ...

Comment: @JamesChevalier it happens at the parser level. The parser sees an assignment and marks `list` as a local variable. Prior to that line, `list` should resolve to the method and return `[]`. Not sure why you got `nil`, maybe the line was already evaluated.

Comment: With `attr_reader :list`, I'd understand this behaviour, because `self.list=` wouldn't be defined. But with `attr_accessor` ? BTW, it really seems to be related to the fact that `a=a` is nil when `a` is undefined.

Comment: @EricDuminil that's how Ruby works – assignment methods always need an explicit receiver.

Comment: @Stefan : Got it, thanks. I didn't notice the documentation excerpt. You could explain why the local variable `list` is nil, and your answer would be perfect.

Comment: ... and this actually allows you to have both, local variables and instance method: `list=` assigns to a local variable and `self.list=` calls the method. If Ruby would treat `list=` as a method call, it would be impossible to create a local variable with the same name.

Comment: “assignment methods always need an explicit receiver”—or an explicit method invocation `method(:list=).call(42)` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa not sure if that is explicit or implicit ;-) BTW, `send(:list=, 42)` would also work.

Comment: Since the public accessor is declared, pedantic rubyists call `public_send`!

Comment: Excellent answer. You might say *when* the expansion of the [abbreviated assignment](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment) by the parser takes place.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `list += _some_method(options)` is internally compiling into `list = list + _some_method(options)`. Despite the existence of a `list` method, Ruby interprets `list = :anything` as defining a new local variable called `list`, overriding the interpretation of `list` within the scope of the method call. When Ruby mistakenly jumps to the 'local variable' conclusion, it has to be told with `self.`. This is why switching to `self.list += _some_method(options)` works.

```
class Thing
    def foo; 'BAR'; end
    def baz; foo = 'ODD'; foo; end
end

Thing.new.foo #=> "BAR" 
Thing.new.baz #=> "ODD"
```

But I agree using `list <<` followed by a `flatten(1)` is still more efficient.

Comment: `list.push(*_some_method(options))` is probably even more efficient. And `.concat` should top even that :)

Comment: Yeah, I ran a benchmark comparing the 3 & push/concat do slightly out-perform shovel/flatten - https://gist.github.com/JamesChevalier/1a6fabde0b56c08691aecb48a37c7174

Comment: I use `list +=` when I'm appending one list with another, e.g.: `numbers += [3,4,5]` adds three new Numeric elements to `numbers` while `numbers << [3,4,5]` adds one Array element. Seems like `list.concat` is the in-place version of `list +=`, if that's what you actually need. In fact, I bet `list + x` is just implemented as `list.dup.concat(x)`.

Comment: _"I bet `list + x` is just implemented as `list.dup.concat(x)`"_ – `Array#+` creates a new array with the final size and `memcpy`s both arrays into it. That's more efficient than duplicating and resizing.

Comment: Curious about the fact that the debugger returns a `list` of `nil` before the `list +=` statement. I modified my test code as follows:

Comment: class Thing
        def foo; 'BAR'; end
        def baz; before = foo; foo = 'ODD'; [before, foo]; end
    end
Thing.new.baz

Comment: Wierd StackOverflow formatting aside, `Thing.new.baz` returns `["BAR", "ODD"]`, which suggests `foo` returns the method call before `foo =` and the local variable after.