# Trying to understand the shovel operator with strings

Tags: ruby, string

I'm going through http://rubykoans.com/

In the koans/about_strings.rb:100 file

```
  def test_the_shovel_operator_modifies_the_original_string
    original_string = "Hello, "
    hi = original_string
    there = "World"
    hi << there
    assert_equal "Hello, World", original_string

    # THINK ABOUT IT:
    #
    # Ruby programmers tend to favor the shovel operator (<<) over the
    # plus equals operator (+=) when building up strings.  Why?
  end
```

This passes, though I would think **original_string** would equal "Hello, " and that **hi** would equal "Hello, World"

I saw this poster had a similar question, but not quite:

[Why is the shovel operator (<<) preferred over plus-equals (+=) when building a string in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684446/why-is-the-shovel-operator-preferred-over-plus-equals-when-building-a)

What am I missing?

Comment: Who coined the term "shovel operator"?

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen the shovel operator used to concatenate strings. Some more common techniques would be `"#{hi}#{there}"` or `[hi, there].join`.

Comment: Look at line 3 again: in line 3 you *tell* Ruby to *make* them the same! Therefore, they *are* the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `hi = original_string` your `hi` variable is just a new variable pointed at the same object.  If you look at `hi.object_id` and `original_string.object_id` you will find they are the same.  If you want a clone of an object that you can manipulate without impacting the
`original_string`, you'll need to say something like `hi = original_string.clone` or `hi = original_string.dup`.