# Reverse a String in Ruby by Reading Backwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just practicing and learning while loops and conditionals (not yet into arrays). I'm trying to reverse any string by concatenating letters, starting from the last letter of the word to the first. eg., for cat, start at t, then a, then c to get tac.

I don't get what's wrong in the code. I'm wondering why the 6th line ( reverse += letter) gives the error message:

> 6: in `+': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)

What's being nil'ed?

```
def is_reversed(word)
  i = word.length
  reverse = ""
  while i > word.length || i != -1
    letter = word[i]
    reverse += letter
    i = i - 1
  end
  return reverse
end

puts is_reversed("cat")
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied your code correctly? I think you meant to write `reverse += letter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issue here but the bottom line is that you're looping wrong. You can either count up to a number or down from a number and it looks like you want to count down by starting at `word.length`. That's fine, but let's look and see what you're actually doing.

With `while i > word.length || i != -1` you're checking each iteration that `i` is...greater than the length of the word? How would it get that way (you're not adding to `i` anywhere) and why would you want to check that?

Since you chose to count down, we want to stop when there are no letters remaining. So change your condition to `while i > 0`. Now we will loop only while there are letters left to go through.

There's another problem though - because indices start at 0, trying to get `word[i]` when `i == 3` will get you `nil`! So you actually want to move the `i = i - 1` to be the first line within your loop.

After these changes, you should have:

```
def is_reversed(word)
  i = word.length
  reverse = ""
  while i > 0
    i = i - 1
    letter = word[i]
    reverse += letter
  end
  return reverse
end

puts is_reversed("cat")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_reversed(word)
  i = word.length
  reverse = ""
  while i > word.length || i != -1
    i = i - 1
    letter = word[i]
    reverse += letter
  end
  return reverse
end

puts is_reversed("cat") 
// will return 'tact'
```

Very first time in the loop above you're trying to find the letter you're putting the index as `word.length` which actually doesn't exist & hence returns `nil` which threw the error.
To get the last letter of a string you'll have to do `i = i - 1` before you do anything else inside the loop.

Second, I think your condition is flawed. If you try to find the element at `-1` in an array or string in ruby it will give you the last element.
And the first condition `i > word.length` will never satisfy as `i`'s value is `word.length`.

So you can do something like this

```
def is_reversed(word)
  i = word.length
  reverse = ""
  while i > 0
    i = i - 1
    letter = word[i]
    reverse += letter
  end
  return reverse
end

puts is_reversed("cat") 

//returns 'tac'
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this has been answered, but how about something more like:

```
def is_reversed(w)
  w.split("").each_with_object("").with_index{ |(l,a), i| a << w[(w.length-1-i)] }
end
```

In console:

```
is_reversed('this is reversed')
=> "desrever si siht"
is_reversed('and so is this')
=> "siht si os dna"
is_reversed('antidisestablishmentarianism')
=> "msinairatnemhsilbatsesiditna"
```

Notes:

- 105 characters instead of 152
- 3 lines instead of 10
- Uses `<<` instead of `+=` (which is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684446/why-is-the-shovel-operator-preferred-over-plus-equals-when-building-a))
- Avoids the `while i > 0` bit which is, IMO, not very idiomatic Ruby
- Avoids unnecessary variable assignments (`i = word.length`, `reverse = ""`, `i = i - 1`, and `letter = word[i]`)