# Ruby differences between += and << to concatenate a string

Tags: ruby, string

On Ruby 1.8.7 I was doing a loop concatenating strings when found out that there seems to be a HUGE difference between `<<` and `+=` on a `String` object:

```
 y = ""
 start = Time.now
 99999.times { |x| y += "some new string"  }
 puts "Time: #{Time.now - start}"
 # Time: 31.56718

 y=''
 start = Time.now
 99999.times { |x| y << "some new string"  }
 puts "Time: #{Time.now - start}"
 # Time: 0.018256
```

I google about that, found some results:

http://www.rubylove.info/post/1038516765/difference-between-string-concatenation-ruby-rails

Says that `<<` modifies both strings, while `+=` only modify the caller. I don't understand why is then `<<` faster.

Next I went to the Ruby doc, but I wonder WHY there is no method `+=`

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684446/why-is-the-shovel-operator-preferred-over-plus-equals-when-building-a (Actually, this might even be a duplicate?)

Comment: The article that you link to that says `<<` modifies both strings is incorrect. The `original` and `copy` variables are referencing the same string object.

Comment: @Adrian Correct. The author of that article seems to have misunderstood what was happening with that code. In fact the "copy" isn't really a copy at all, just a reference to the same String object.

Comment: On Ruby 2.7, the time is 10.923654 and 0.005134.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The shovel operator `<<` performs much better than `+=` when dealing with long strings because the shovel operator is allowed to modify the original string, whereas `+=` has to copy all the text from the first string into a new string every time it runs.

There is no `+=` operator defined on the String class, because `+=` is a combined operator. In short `x += "asdf"` is exactly equivalent to `x = x + "asdf"`, so you should reference the `+` operator on the string class, not look for a `+=` operator.