# ruby operator confusion with shovel (<<) and += , Concating arrays

Tags: ruby, operators, concatenation

I've read some of the differences between << +=. But i think i may not understand these differences, because my expected code doesn't output what i want to achieve.

in response to [Ruby differences between += and << to concatenate a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990933/ruby-differences-between-and-to-concatenate-a-string?lq=1)

I want to unscramble "Cat" into an array of its letters/words
=> ["c", "ca", "cat", "a", "at", "t"]

```
def helper(word)
words_array = []
idx = 0
while idx < word.length 
    j = idx  
    temp = ""
    while j < word.length
        **temp << word[j]**
        words_array << temp unless words_array.include?(temp) 
    j += 1 
    end
    idx += 1 
end 
p words_array
end
helper("cat")
```

I don't understand why
temp << word[j]
is different from temp += word[j] when to me my logic in this specific case is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One difference is that because `<<` works in place it is somewhat faster than `+=`. The following code

```
require 'benchmark'

a = ''
b= ''

puts Benchmark.measure {
  100000.times { a << 'test' }
}

puts Benchmark.measure {
  100000.times { b += 'test' }
}
```

yields

```
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004653)
0.060000   0.060000   0.120000 (  0.108534)
```

**Update**

I originally misunderstood the question. Here's whats going on. Ruby variables only store references to objects, not the objects themselves. Here's simplified code that does the same thing as yours, and has the same issue. I've told it to print `temp` and `words_array` on each iteration of the loops.

```
def helper(word)
  words_array = []

  word.length.times do |i|
    temp = ''
    (i...word.length).each do |j|
      temp << word[j]
      puts "temp:\t#{temp}"
      words_array << temp unless words_array.include?(temp)
      puts "words:\t#{words_array}"
    end
  end

  words_array
end

p helper("cat")
```

Here is what it prints:

```
temp:   c
words:  ["c"]
temp:   ca
words:  ["ca"]
temp:   cat
words:  ["cat"]
temp:   a
words:  ["cat", "a"]
temp:   at
words:  ["cat", "at"]
temp:   t
words:  ["cat", "at", "t"]
["cat", "at", "t"]
```

As you can see, during each iteration of the inner loop after the first, ruby is simply replacing the last element of `words_array`. That is because `words_array` holds a reference to the string object referenced by `temp`, and `<<` modifies that object in place rather than creating a new object.

On each iteration of the outer loop `temp` is set to a new object, and that new object is appended to `words_array`, so it doesn't replace the previous elements.

The `+=` construct returns a new object to `temp` on each iteration of the inner loop, which is why it does behave as expected.

Comment: Aren't you comparing exactly the same thing here?

Comment: Thanks @sagarpandya82. I fixed it.

Comment: I agree that using the shovel method is faster, but I was wondering in my specific case why the shovel versus += is different, because the logic to me makes sense

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 2):

✓ `temp << word[j]` modifies the `temp` inplace;

✓ `temp += word[j]`, which is a shorthand for `temp = temp + word[j]`, creates another object and assigns it to `temp` variable.

BTW:

```
input = 'cat'.split('')
(1..input.length).each_with_object([]) do |i, memo|
  memo << input.each_cons(i).to_a
end.flatten(1).map(&:join)
#⇒ [
#    [0] "c",
#    [1] "a",
#    [2] "t",
#    [3] "ca",
#    [4] "at",
#    [5] "cat"
#  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# this code might be easier to follow
word = "cat"

def helper(word)
  letter_array = []
  copy_cat = word
  word.length.times do
    starts = 0
    ends = 0
    loop do
      letter_array << copy_cat[starts..ends]
      ends += 1
      break if ends == copy_cat.length
    end
    copy_cat.delete!(word[0])
  end
  letter_array
end

p helper(word) # returns ["c", "ca", "cat", "a", "at", "t"]
```